# R: K-fold CV simplifying the code

Tags: r, machine-learning, cross-validation

I'm doing 3-fold CV for regression from scratch. I wrote a code which is very simple but with is like "hard coded". I want to simplify the code so I could use it for bigger matrices too, and with a larger number of folds. Here is the idea, that I implemented.

I have a matrix **X[6x10]**  and I generate the dependent matrix **Y[6x1]**. I split X into 3 parts, and Y: [image: Matrix divided into 3 folds]

Then I concatenate X1 with X2 and create a **X1,2[4x10]**, I do the same with X1, X3 and create a **X1,3** and with X2, X3 I create a **X2,3**. These X-es I use to generate **Y1,2[4x1]**, **Y1,2** and **Y1,2**. And to generate the beta coefficients, 
[image][10x1], 
[image] and 
[image].

I use the estimated betas to generate the **Y_est**-estimate(or y hat).

[image]

[image]

[image]

Then I find the square error for each Y set, so:

[image]

[image]

[image]

And then I compute the mean of these square errors: [image]

Here is the code that does this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
require(stats)
require(caret)
set.seed(1)
mat=matrix(sample.int(10, 9*100, TRUE), 6, 10)
#Randomly shuffle the data 
mat=mat[sample(nrow(mat)),]
folds=cut(seq(1, nrow(mat)), breaks = 3, labels = FALSE)
#Perform 10 fold cross validation 
for(i in 1:3){
  #segment your data by folds using the which() function 
  testIndexes=which(folds==i, arr.ind = TRUE)
  testData=mat[testIndexes,]
  trainData=mat[-testIndexes,]
}
#getting the 3 folds
X1=trainData[1:2,]
X2=trainData[3:4,]
X3=testData
#generating y from the folds
Y1=as.matrix(apply(X1[, 1:10], 1, sum) + rnorm(2))
Y2=as.matrix(apply(X2[, 1:10], 1, sum) + rnorm(2))
Y3=as.matrix(apply(X3[, 1:10], 1, sum) + rnorm(2))
#concatenating the rows together for X
X12=rbind(X1,X2)
X13=rbind(X1,X3)
X23=rbind(X2,X3)
#concatenating the rows together for Y
Y12=rbind(Y1, Y2)
Y13=rbind(Y1, Y3)
Y23=rbind(Y2, Y3)
#computing beta
beta12=(t(X12)%*%X12)%*%t(X12)%*%Y12 
beta13=(t(X12)%*%X12)%*%t(X12)%*%Y12 
beta23=(t(X12)%*%X12)%*%t(X12)%*%Y12 
#Y hat estimate
Y1_hat=X1%*%beta23
Y2_hat=X2%*%beta13
Y3_hat=X3%*%beta12
#calculating the error 
err_Y1=(Y1-Y1_hat)^2
err_Y2=(Y2-Y2_hat)^2
err_Y3=(Y3-Y3_hat)^2
#computing the mean of the errors
mse=(err_Y1+err_Y2+err_Y3)/3
```

Is there any way to simplify this code so I could use it for bigger matrices and with a higher number of folds? I would very much appreciate your input.

Comment: perhaps examine the code for [`cv.glmnet`](https://github.com/cran/glmnet/blob/master/R/cv.glmnet.R), which does so internally

Comment: @MichaelChirico thanks, I will do that